# how to get the min maven.target.version out of the dependency tree

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

is there a way to find out the maven.target.version that i should use in my project out of the dependency tree?

i'd like to update the versions of some libraries used in my project and want to make sure none of them is using a higher target version than the one i'm using (1.5).

i'm compiling my projects with jenkins and it would be nice to catch the errors at compile time or when testing and not at runtime on the server. as i am building more than one project with jenkins changing the jvm jenkins uses to compile to 1.5 isn't an option as the other projects would fail then.

Comment: I would compile it using Java version 1.5, this would show an error if you did.

Comment: thks i added a clarification that this isn't an option as i'm using a CI to compile the projects and i don't know a way to set a specific jdk for a single project

Comment: In Hudson or Jenkins its a project option. Which CI are you using?

Comment: i'm using jenkins, the project is a maven 2 project, i can't find an option to set the jdk to 1.5

Comment: Its one of the "Advanced options" for the module in Hudson, I assume Jenkins is the same (its the same code base)

Comment: as peter pointed out:
compile the projects with the jdk you need to match.

in jenkins you have to configure your jdk for each project if you have configured more than one jdk in the global jenkins settings.

Comment: you realise you are talking to yourself. ;)